# Take first Rights from list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, either

Firstly, I have a (infinite) list of `Either`s, which is produced like this:

```
x :: A
...

f :: A -> Either B A
...

xs :: [Either B A]
xs = iterate (>>=f) (Right x)
```

The list will contain several `Right`s (always a finite number) and then the same `Left` value repeated. What I need is to take all the `Right`s and one `Left` after them. In this particular case it can be done also by changing the function for example, but I'm also interested in best general method.

Comment: @is7s: it was a mistype) Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me suggest a more invasive change. Instead of

```
x :: A
f :: A -> Either B A
xs :: [Either B A]
```

consider

```
x :: A
f :: A -> Writer [A] B
```

and forget `xs` entirely. Where before `f` was a single step of the iteration, it is now recursive; where before it would return `Right a`, you now `tell [a] >> f a`; where before it would return `Left b`, you now `return b`.

If it's really necessary, you can still access the individual pieces of the `Writer`, namely the `[A]` and `B`, via `execWriter` and `evalWriter` (or by using `runWriter` to access them both at once):

```
xs :: [A]
b :: B
(xs, b) = runWriter (f x)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`span`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aspan) to split the list between the `Right` elements and the `Left` ones, then pattern match to grab the first `Left`.

```
(rights, firstLeft : _) = span isRight xs
    where isRight (Right _) = True
          isRight _         = False
```

Comment: You can also define "isRight = either (const False) (const True)"

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this, if you need to keep them all in the same list:

```
answer = map fst . takeWhile snd $ zip xs (True : map isRight xs)
  where isRight (Right _) = True
        isRight _         = False
```

(Why aren't `isRight` and `isLeft` defined in Data.Either?)